# How do you cancel all Google Cloud Pub/Sub push notifications that are failing?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I had an error in my servlet which is causing the servlet to crash when getting a Cloud Pub/Sub. However, Cloud Pub/Sub keeps trying to send notifications to that servlet. Is there a kill switch for this? To just stop all those notifications that are trying over and over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to prevent redelivery of individual Google Cloud Pub/Sub messages is to successfully ack them (by returning a success HTTP response code) or wait the seven days for them to expire. If your goal is to stop all delivery of messages until the servlet is fixed to prevent the error, then you can temporarily [configure the subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#create) as a pull subscription by removing the push endpoint. Once you've deployed a servlet without the error, you can switch back to a push subscription by putting back the push endpoint, at which point redelivery of all messages will begin.